# How to save data from parse to a NSArray in a certain format

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, pfquery

I set a property of array of sampleData as follow:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sampleData;
```

And I want this array to have a format something like this:

```
self.sampleData = @[ @{ @"createdAt": @"date A",
                        @"text":  @"text A"
                      },
                    @{ @"createdAt": @"date B",
                        @"text":  @"text B"
                      }
                ];
```

My issue is that the actual data will come from **parse.com** database and I don't know how to save that into my sampleData in that said format.

Here below is what I've gone about it so far which is still missing the part to save data from parse to sampleData array:

```
PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAWParsePostsClassKey];
[postQuery whereKey:kPAWParseUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[postQuery includeKey:kPAWParseUserKey];

postQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
postQuery.limit = 20;

[postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *myPosts, NSError *error)
 {
     if( !error )
     {
         NSLog(@"My Post --> %@", myPosts);

         //self.sampleData = mySpotPosts; //this is definitely not right so need help here

     }
 }
];
```

And here is the NSlog output:

```
 My Post --> (
 "<Posts:QJzFvbkKPO:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195a0bd0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x17af9da0>\";\n    text = \"Yuangi brunch\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:fhQAiGeVqI:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x19368c90>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x1945ed00>\";\n    text = \"Nanliao harbor, hsinju\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:jT5x9ySzW6:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x194b7510>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19565630>\";\n    text = Nanjuang;\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:5iMO83El7z:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x19542fc0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x194bc620>\";\n    text = \"Carrefour, Neihu\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:51HRgSopVN:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1940d3b0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19467510>\";\n    text = \"Www.thecubeinn.com.tw\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n    whoLiked =     (\n    );\n}",
 "<Posts:DyRBc0iIyW:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x19493360>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x194d65a0>\";\n    text = \"Www.thecubeinn.com.tw\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n    whoLiked =     (\n    );\n}",
 "<Posts:PgmZdTLIVt:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x193c81b0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19350b20>\";\n    text = \"Mei Hua Hu Lake\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:LUBu0s5Bkt:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1949b120>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195e35a0>\";\n    text = \"Surprisingly very good food here\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:6fHRjfO36A:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x194dca40>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195ca270>\";\n    text = \"Village Churasco\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:4PeJdGSpOw:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x165a21f0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195be6a0>\";\n    text = \"Wang long pei \";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:7cYuel47k8:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x193f7760>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195d7660>\";\n    text = \"R den dessert factory\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:vOGFIotiOc:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x193ce0b0>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x195a21a0>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x16560c10>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19532620>\";\n    text = \"Home pic2\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:SDdAJxgIvF:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195e5a70>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x17ae3800>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x1651c4f0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19350320>\";\n    text = \"Home pic3\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:t6VBfj0Dv1:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195c7860>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x1655c5b0>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x195a6460>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x17a25ba0>\";\n    text = \"Home pic4\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:nUtog76u7q:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195d9050>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x17a507f0>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x19542e30>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195e0850>\";\n    text = \"Home pic5\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:XxOLjsdO5u:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195d7450>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x17a6a2f0>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x195dcb20>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x195d9950>\";\n    text = \"Home pic6\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:UauisYVrQX:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x19582e20>\";\n    imageFile = \"<PFFile: 0x194b7b00>\";\n    imageFileTH = \"<PFFile: 0x19314340>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x19327550>\";\n    text = \"Home pic7\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:TvUu5q4ijc:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x195504b0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x194c8de0>\";\n    text = \"Yana's home\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n    whoLiked =     (\n        4689S87hx5\n    );\n}",
 "<Posts:u2DoXMia6G:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1934b6d0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x1934f730>\";\n    text = \"The Cube inn\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}",
 "<Posts:rijY1Y4jQI:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x16573090>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x1941ae20>\";\n    text = \"The Cube inn1\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}"
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of your `if (!error) {...` should be something along the lines of:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"]; // Set to whatever format you want your dates to be
NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (PFObject *object in myPosts) {
  [objectArray addObject:@{@"createdAt": [formatter stringFromDate:object.createdAt], @"text": [object objectForKey:@"text"]}];
}
self.sampleData = objectArray;
```

Comment: Hi @rickerbh even though I accepted your answer to this question, I realised my sampleData now requires some grouping to align with my coding to display those data to a view. Here's the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317469/add-objects-to-nsmutable-array-with-grouping) to my further question. Hope you get interested to help me out.