# Add objects to NSMutable array with grouping

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, pfquery

I want my NSArray sampleData to receive actual data from parse.com database assuming like this:

```
self.sampleData = @[ @{ @"date": @"12/5/2014",
                        @"group": @[ @{ @"text": @"post1", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post2", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post3", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post4", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post5", @"location": @"x,y" }
                                   ]
                        },
                     @{ @"date": @"12/3/2014",
                        @"group": @[ @{ @"text": @"post6", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post7", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post8", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post9", @"location": @"x,y" },
                                     @{ @"text": @"post10", @"location": @"x,y" }
                                   ]
                        }
                  ];
```

As you can see, I want to group text and location by date, so that I can display them in a view with  date as header and text/location as content.
Here below is what I'm capable doing so far:

```
PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAWParsePostsClassKey];
[postQuery whereKey:kPAWParseUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

postQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
postQuery.limit = 20;

[postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *myPosts, NSError *error)
 {
     if( !error )
     {

         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; 

         NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray new];

         for (PFObject *object in myPosts) {
             [objectArray addObject:@{@"createdAt": [formatter stringFromDate:object.createdAt], @"text": [object objectForKey:@"text"], @"location": [object objectForKey:@"location"]}];
         }

         self.sampleData = objectArray;
         NSLog(@"My sampleData --> %@", self.sampleData);

     }
 }
];
```

The above code is obvious there's no grouping whatsoever, so really need help here.

Comment: I've come across to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375528/rebuild-an-nsarray-by-grouping-objects-that-have-matching-id-numbers/15375756#15375756) and it seems pretty close to my question but I still can't understand it.

Comment: What is the format of the data in `myPosts` ?

Comment: It's data on Parse.com. It looks like this: objectId(string), location(GeoPoint), text(String), createdAt(Date), ...

Comment: Just to give you what I'm trying to do please see this [link](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/). This is exactly what I want to display my data but I've been stuck with how to replace sampleData with my actual data from Parse.com.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parse.  Can you log `NSLog(@"%@",myPosts);` and copy the output?  I suspect the data is already in the right format.

Comment: Something like this
("<Posts:fhQAiGeVqI:(null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x1a31d9b0>\";\n    location = \"<PFGeoPoint: 0x1a3083e0>\";\n    text = \"Nanliao harbor, hsinju\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:4689S87hx5>\";\n}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have an array of items, and you want to group them into sections based on a particular key.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

// Sparse dictionary, containing keys for "days with posts"
NSMutableDictionary *daysWithPosts = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[myPosts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[object createdAt]];

    // Check to see if we have a day already.
    NSMutableArray *posts = [daysWithPosts objectForKey: dateString];

    // If not, create it
    if (posts == nil || (id)posts == [NSNull null])
    {
        posts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
        [daysWithPosts setObject:posts forKey: dateString];
    }

    // add post to day
    [posts addObject:obj];
}];

// Sort Dictionary Keys by Date
NSArray *unsortedSectionTitles = [daysWithPosts allKeys];
NSArray *sortedSectionTitles = [unsortedSectionTitles sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];
    return [date2 compare:date1];
}];

NSMutableArray *sortedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sortedSectionTitles.count];

// Put Data into correct format:
[sortedSectionTitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *dateString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray *group = daysWithPosts[dateString];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"date":dateString,
                                  @"group":group };
    [sortedData addObject:dictionary];
}];

self.sampleData = sortedData;
```

This code will not generate **exactly** what you asked for.  It will generate something that looks like this:

```
sampleData = @[ @{ @"date": @"12/5/2014",
                    @"group": @@[ PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                               ]
                    },
                 @{ @"date": @"12/3/2014",
                    @"group": @[ PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject*,
                                 PFObject
                               ]
                    }
              ];
```

There's no need to convert your `PFObject*` in the `myPosts` array into `@{ @"text": @"post5", @"location": @"x,y" }` since you'll lose access to other pieces of information.  Here is how you would use this `sampleData` array.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; {
    return self.sampleData.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
    return self.sampleData[section][@"date"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
    return self.sampleData[section][@"group"].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    PFObject *post = self.sampleData[indexPath.section][@"group"][indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = // dequeue A reusable tableviewcell here

    // configure the cell here

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you also help make keys for text and location at least for experiment? I tried your code but my tableview shows nothing. I'm just wondering if those keys are required as the original sampleData has a key for text. I like your code very much though.

Comment: I have created a key for text to experiment but it's still not working. I'll take more time to dive into it. I've accepted your answer anyway. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SanitLee at this point I think that someone well-versed in `Parse` can help you much more than me.

Comment: Finally found a solution. Just have to refresh the table view on the main thread inside my findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Thanks again @StephenFurlani