# NSDate without time for condition statement in For loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Here below is part of my code:

```
[postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *myPosts, NSError *error)
 {
     if( !error )
     {
         NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
         NSArray *createdAtGroup = [myPosts valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.createdAt"];

         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

         NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
         NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                               fromDate:[NSDate date]];
         NSDate *createdAt = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

        for (createdAt in createdAtGroup)
        {
            NSLog(@"createdAt ------> %@", createdAt);

            NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [entry setObject:[formatter stringFromDate:createdAt] forKey:@"createdAt"];

            NSArray *createdAtSections = [myPosts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt = %@", createdAt]];
            //NSArray *createdAtSections = [myPosts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt = %@", [formatter stringFromDate:createdAt]]];

            for (int i=0; i < createdAtSections.count; i++) {
                NSString *text = [[createdAtSections objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"];
                [entry setObject:text forKey:@"text"];

            }
            [resultArray addObject:entry];
        }
         NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);

     }
 }
];
```

Look at condition statement in For loop:

```
for (createdAt in createdAtGroup)
```

I want **createdAt** declared as **NSDate** without time so that I can group **text** into the same date. As I have searched, there seems no way to extract time from **NSDate**. However, I found this piece of code which they claim to do just that but it doesn't work for me.

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
         NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                               fromDate:[NSDate date]];
         NSDate *createdAt = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Is anyone know if I miss anything here or any other way to achieve this? Thanks.

Here I also give my output:

- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.218  createdAt ------> 2014-10-14 13:45:39 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.224  createdAt ------> 2014-10-14 13:51:18 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.231  createdAt ------> 2014-09-04 09:56:27 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.233  createdAt ------> 2014-09-16 05:28:57 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.235  createdAt ------> 2014-10-23 07:34:15 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.237  createdAt ------> 2014-09-12 03:04:50 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.239  createdAt ------> 2014-09-16 05:12:59 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.246  createdAt ------> 2014-09-16 08:05:54 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.248  createdAt ------> 2014-09-10 06:01:19 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.250  createdAt ------> 2014-09-10 07:17:09 +0000
- 2014-12-08 00:00:56.254  (
      {
      createdAt = "10/14/2014";
      text = "Www.thecubeinn.com.tw";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "10/14/2014";
      text = "Www.thecubeinn.com.tw";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/04/2014";
      text = "Mei Hua Hu Lake";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/16/2014";
      text = Nanjuang;
  },
      {
      createdAt = "10/23/2014";
      text = "Carrefour, Neihu";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/12/2014";
      text = "Yuangi brunch";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/16/2014";
      text = "Surprisingly very good food here";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/16/2014";
      text = "Nanliao harbor, hsinju";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/10/2014";
      text = "Yana's home";
  },
      {
      createdAt = "09/10/2014";
      text = "Wang long pei ";
  }
  )

Comment: Wait... So you want to have a representation of the NSDate but without time? Is that the issue?

Comment: No, I have no problem with its representation as I can just use formatter. I have problem in For loop condition statement.

Comment: What is your actual goal?  Are you trying to group items by their date?  I.e. 10 items on day 1, 5 items on day 2?

Comment: @StephenFurlani exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what you want to do is cycle through all of your items, and put them into buckets that are labeled by days (NSDictionary works well here - NSNumber can even be hashed as a key).

```
// Get the calendar for the user's locale
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

// Sparse dictionary, containing keys for "days with posts"
NSMutableDictionary *daysWithPosts = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[myPosts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    // use this if 'createdAt' is a UTC time-stamp
    // NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[obj createdAt].floatValue];
    // NSNumber *uniqueDay = @([calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitEra forDate:date]); // This is not fast

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[obj createdAt]]; // EDIT 1

    // Check to see if we have a day already.
    NSMutableArray *posts = [daysWithPosts objectForKey: dateString /*uniqueDay*/];

    // If not, create it
    if (posts == nil || (id)posts == [NSNull null])
    {
        posts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
        [daysWithPosts setObject:posts forKey: dateString /*uniqueDay*/];
    }

    // add post to day
    [posts addObject:obj];
}];

// Sections array for TableView
NSArray *sectionTitles = [daysWithPosts allKeys]; // keep this around to re-format to strings?
NSArray *sections = [daysWithPosts allValues];
```

The result is an array of sections and titles which you can use in a Tableview.

```
id rowData = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

You may also want to sort the individual days further based on their individual time.

```
[sections enumeratObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUinteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [(NSMutableArray*)obj sortUsingDescriptors:@[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES]];
}];
```

Comment: I got this error:
2014-12-08 01:10:02.365 -[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x192094e0
2014-12-08 01:10:02.368 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x192094e0'

Comment: I tried your code without fully understanding it and I got above error. I basically put your code in my [postQuery ..] block.

Comment: @SanitLee what is [obj createdAt] ?  is it an NSDate?

Comment: In my original code, createdAt is NSDate. But in your code, I don't know. I'm now wondering this line: NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[obj createdAt]];

Comment: @SanitLee I updated my code example to handle `createdAt` being an `NSDate`.  Try it now.  I'm assuming `createdAt` is a property/method on the objects stored in `myPosts`.  In your original code, you tried to use the method name as a variable.  While possible, it gets confusing.

Comment: I tried your updated code and I got through that error but it doesn't do the grouping yet.

Comment: @SanitLee it should.  When you print `sections` it should give you an array of arrays.  What do you get when you print `sectionTitles`?

Comment: OK my bad that I missed your // Sections array for TableView. Now how can I combine sectionTitles and sections into one array? Also, how can I customise sections for example I want to have only text and location in the array?

Comment: @SanitLee I think at this point you're running into a different question which is: "How do I arrange data for use in a UITableView?"  Search Google and you'll have your answers.  Also, please mark this question as accepted if it did answer your initial question.

Comment: Please bare with me. The reason I want to have one string with that grouping is to align with the rest of the coding to display data in a UITableView+CollectionViewCell. You can see more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317469/add-objects-to-nsmutable-array-with-grouping).Just look at the sampleData. Meanwhile I'll try to study your code and try to go from there. Appreciate!

Comment: with your answer accepted I still hope you to help look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317469/add-objects-to-nsmutable-array-with-grouping). I've been searching as you suggested but none can give me a spark. To be more specific, I want to have a single array combining sectionTitles and sections in a format shown in earlier link to my another question. If I can't do so, I'd have to try to tweak the rest of the code to cope with the change which is way more complex for me. So please help me out or give me some keywords at least. Million thanks.